# PAM unable to dlopen(/lib64/security/pam_fprintd.so) causing CentOS/Redhat server to crash

Tags: centos, centos6, pam, server-crashes

CentOS 6, Parallels PLESK 10.4, Apache

One of my servers went down over the weekend much to my dismay.  On the day and time it occurred, my log errors/messages end with this -

**/var/log/secure:**

```
Jul 29 03:53:15 u######## su: PAM adding faulty module: 
  /lib64/security/pam_fprintd.so
Jul 29 03:53:15 u######## su: pam_unix(su-l:session): 
  session opened for user popuser by (uid=0)
Jul 29 03:53:16 u######## su: pam_unix(su-l:session): 
  session closed for user popuser
Jul 29 03:53:16 u######## su: PAM unable to dlopen(/lib64/security/pam_fprintd.so):
 /lib64/security/pam_fprintd.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
 directory
Jul 29 03:53:16 u######## su: PAM adding faulty module: 
 /lib64/security/pam_fprintd.so
Jul 29 03:53:16 u######## su: pam_unix(su-l:session):
 session opened for user popuser by (uid=0)
Jul 29 03:53:18 u######## su: pam_unix(su-l:session): 
 session closed for user popuser
```

then immediately afterwards,

**/var/log/messages:**

```
Jul 29 03:53:21 u######## kernel: imklog 4.6.2, log source = /proc/kmsg started.
Jul 29 03:53:21 u######## rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="4.6.2"
 x-pid="1370" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] (re)start
```

**/var/log/messages (of that day):**

```
Jul 29 03:53:21 u######## rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="4.6.2"
 x-pid="1370" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] rsyslogd was HUPed,type 'restart'.
Jul 29 03:53:21 u######## kernel: Kernel logging (proc) stopped.
```

**And from /var/log/cron**

```
Jul 29 03:53:20 u######## run-parts(/etc/cron.daily)[29257]: starting awstats
Jul 29 03:53:20 u######## run-parts(/etc/cron.daily)[32242]: finished awstats
Jul 29 03:53:20 u######## run-parts(/etc/cron.daily)[29257]: starting logrotate
```

That's the last message I get before the server goes down.  Everything I've Googled leads me to believe that the `session opened for user popuser` is a fairly common log entry and shouldn't be considered a threat, but for some reason I interpret that as something not so nice.

Others have mentioned that PAM adding a faulty module could be a bug?  I don't even know what PAM is....

Any insight on how to interpret these would be greatly appreciated.  I've checked

```
/var/log/secure
/var/log/messages
/var/log/cron
```

Are there any other places I could look into to help diagnose this?

Many thanks, SF.

Comment: Who are you hosting the server with? Is it possible that your hosting company had an outage or something? also, since a restart was issued, did the server actually come back up or did you have to start it back up yourself?

Comment: @Hersheezy, I was away on vacation (of course) so someone from my company called 1&1 (the company that has the server) and they rebooted it for them.  No explanation was given to them, so I am investigating it now.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Jul 29 03:53:15 u######## su: PAM adding faulty module: 
  /lib64/security/pam_fprintd.so
```

It looks like a bug: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=505266

Install `authconfig` and try this:

```
authconfig --disablefingerprint --update
```

Comment: many thanks.  This definitely provides insight on the matter.  It's nice to finally see someone else have this issue so it's not a fluke.